# How to write bson form of mongo query in golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I can query my mongodb collection to get the ipv4Addresses based on the nfType and the minimum distance using the command line query

```
db.nfinstancesdb.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "nfType": "AMF"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$ipv4Addresses"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$distance",
      "ipv4Addresses": {
        "$addToSet": "$ipv4Addresses"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

This give the output am expecting as

```
[{"_id": 10,"ipv4Addresses": ["172.16.0.11","172.16.0.10"]}]
```

How can I write the bson form of the above query on Go?

I did in the function below but am getting all the ipv4Addresses
instead of the above result.

```
func (m *NfInstanceDataAccess) FindIp(nfType string) ([]NfInstance, error) {
    var ip []NfInstance

    collection := db.C(COLLECTION)
    pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
        {{"$match", bson.D{
            {"nfType", "AMF"},
        }}},
        {{"$unwind", "$ipv4Addresses"}},
        {{"$group", bson.D{
            {"_id", "$distance"},
            {"ipv4Addresses", bson.D{
                {"$addToSet", "$ipv4Addresses"},
            }},
        }}},
        {{"$sort", bson.D{
            {"_id", 1},
        }}},
        {{"$limit", 1}},
    }

    cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
    defer cursor.Close(context.Background())
    for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
        var ip []NfInstance
        err := cursor.Decode(&ip)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        //fmt.Println(doc)
    }
    return ip, nil
}
```

My collection has the following items

```
{
    "nfInstanceID": "1",
    "nfType": [
      "AMF"
    ],
    "nfStatus": [
      "REGISTERED"
    ],
    "ipv4Addresses": [
      "172.16.0.10"
    ],
    "distance": 10
  },
  {
    "nfInstanceID": "2",
    "nfType": [
      "UPF"
    ],
    "nfStatus": [
      "REGISTERED"
    ],
    "ipv4Addresses": [
      "172.16.0.20"
    ],
    "distance": 20
  },
  {
    "nfInstanceID": "3",
    "nfType": [
      "AMF"
    ],
    "nfStatus": [
      "REGISTERED"
    ],
    "ipv4Addresses": [
      "172.16.0.30"
    ],
    "distance": 30
  },
  {
    "nfInstanceID": "4",
    "nfType": [
      "AMF"
    ],
    "nfStatus": [
      "REGISTERED"
    ],
    "ipv4Addresses": [
      "172.16.0.11"
    ],
    "distance": 10
  }
```

And I am expecting the same or similar output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your golang code is you didn't group.

You can make use of `Pipe` which prepares a pipeline to aggregate:

```
pipe := db.C(COLLECTION).Pipe([]bson.M{
    {"$match":  bson.M{"nfType": "AMF"}},
    {"$unwind": "$ipv4Addresses"},
    {"$group":  bson.M{
                       "_id": "$distance",
                       "ipv4Addresses": bson.M{"$addToSet": "$ipv4Addresses"},
                      }},
    {"$sort": bson.M{"_id": 1}},
    {"$limit": 1},

})

err := pipe.All(&ip)
```

Comment: Yes there is syntax errors  "missing key in map literal"  in {"$unwind": bson.M{"$ipv4Addresses"}}, and bson.M{"$distance"}

Comment: I have tried changing them  to  

{"$unwind": "$ipv4Addresses"}, and 
bson.M{"_id": "$distance"}

but it not working.

Comment: No error after the change but it did not provide the ipv4addresses with the distance 10. It provides all the ipv4addresses.

Comment: @danielwilson i added sort and limit to the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the official [MongoDB Go driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) you can utilise [Collection.Aggregate](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.Aggregate) to perform [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). The example Go code snippet that you posted is using `find()` which is different than aggregation.

For example, using MongoDB Go driver v1.0.4 (current):

```
collection := client.Database("dbname").Collection("collname")
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
    {{"$match", bson.D{
        {"nfType", "AMF"},
    }}}, 
    {{"$unwind", "$ipv4Addresses"}},
    {{"$group", bson.D{
        {"_id", "$distance"},
        {"ipv4Addresses", bson.D{
            {"$addToSet", "$ipv4Addresses"},
        }},
    }}}, 
    {{"$sort", bson.D{
        {"_id", 1},
    }}}, 
    {{"$limit", 1}},
}

cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
defer cursor.Close(context.Background())
for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
    doc := bson.D{}
    err := cursor.Decode(&doc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(doc)
}
```

The example documents that you posted only have 1 element for all of `ipv4Addresses`, I'm assuming that this is just an example. If however, all of the documents do only have 1 element array for `ipv4Addresses` you're likely better off to just use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

Generally [bson.D](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) is used when serialising to BSON (and when order matters).

Comment: Am trying to integrate the code into the function FindIp above and am getting "collection.Aggregate undefined  (type *mgo.Collection has no filed or method Aggregate)" error.

Comment: Looks like you’re using ‘mgo’ module instead of ‘mongo-go-driver’